# Log.e doesnt show off in Logcat ( Android Studio )

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging, logcat

Hey I am struggling now about this for half an hour..
Could anyone say why Log.e is not showing up? I tried many Combination of Filter regex and Log level butn ive never seen anything

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od1xc.png)

Answer (score 0):

change this to your app, your app is DEAD

[image]

Comment: that was after I quit my Aplication. Not worked when selected

Answer (score 0):

```
PHSDKListener Listener=new PHSDKListener ()

 {
 }
```

This function is not called by your code...For error check your logcat .

Comment: it is cause if im typing something wrong here this app crashes at exact this point

Answer (score 0):

You have to check some criteria:

- The code reaches your log (check with a breakpoint)
- The right device is selected, even if you have only one device sometimes adb clones it and two of them appear
- The process of your app must be running
- Your app must have debuggable set to true. It is by default but sometimes you're running on a release build or changed it by accident in a debug build
- Android Device Monitor can't be running

If all else fails run logcat on the command line with no filters just to be sure.